# ImageFolder does not work in remote machine

Tags: python, pytorch, remote-server

So, I need to access a remote machine where ImageNet is installed. I already downloaded on my local computers the tars I need to train my neural network, and I used random_split() to split each tar in 80% trainset, 10% valset and 10% testset. The names of the images for each set were appended to a txt file, that I wanted to use as a check-passage.

So, I wrote python script that I wanted to launch on the remote machine. The file has to pass over the folders of the ImageNet database and based on txt files I sent to the machine, include only the pics that are "named" in the file.
Here's the script:

```
import os
import torch
from torch.utils.data import random_split
from torchvision.datasets import ImageFolder
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import time
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import datasets, models, transforms
from torch import nn
import copy

def set_seed(seed):
    """ Random seed generation for PyTorch. See https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html
        for further details.
    Args:
        seed (int): the seed for pseudonumber generation.
    """
    import random
    import numpy as np
    import torch

    if seed is not None:
        random.seed(seed)

        np.random.seed(seed)

        torch.manual_seed(seed)
        torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
        torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
        torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False

set_seed(42)

def is_valid_trfile(fname):
    with open('/home/fdalligna/hopelessly_trying/training.txt', 'r') as f:
        text = f.read().split()
    if fname.endswith('.JPEG'):
        return True
    elif fname in text:
        return True
    else: 
        return False


trainset = ImageFolder(root = '/media/data/Datasets/imagenet/winter21_whole', is_valid_file = is_valid_trfile)


def is_valid_vlfile(fname):
    with open('/home/fdalligna/hopelessly_trying/validating.txt', 'r') as f:
        text = f.read().split()
    if fname.endswith('.JPEG'):
        return True
    elif fname in text:
        return True
    else:
        return False


valset = ImageFolder(root = '/media/data/Datasets/imagenet/winter21_whole', is_valid_file = is_valid_vlfile)


def is_valid_tsfile(fname):
    with open('/home/fdalligna/hopelessly_trying/testing.txt', 'r') as f:
        text = f.read().split()
    if fname.endswith('.JPEG'):
        return True
    elif fname in text:
        return True
    else:
        return False


testset = ImageFolder(root = '/media/data/Datasets/imagenet/winter21_whole', is_valid_file = is_valid_tsfile)

assert trainset == 32298
assert valset == 4023
assert testset == 4064

print('everything ok')
```

I inserted the `assert` because I wanted it to check that the size of the sets were correct.

However, I get this error:

```
trainset = ImageFolder(root= /media/data/Datasets/imagenet/winter21_whole'
is_valid_file = is_valid_trfile)
File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py
line 209, in __init__
is_valid_file=is_valid_file)
File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py
line 97, in __init__
"Supported extensions are: " + ",".join (extensions)))
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

I don't know what to do and how to solve the problem. Does anyone know?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to remove the option of is_valid_file

Comment: @Phoenix I need the is_valid_file to make sure it gets the right images and not the whole ImageNet dataset!!

Comment: Just to see the source of the error, then you can return it back.

Comment: `
File "should.py", line 46, in <module>
    trainset = ImageFolder(root = '/media/data/Datasets/imagenet/winter21_whole')
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py", line 209, in __init__
    is_valid_file=is_valid_file)
  File "/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py", line 97, in __init__
    "Supported extensions are: " + ",".join(extensions)))
RuntimeError: Found 0 files in subfolders of: /media/data/Datasets/imagenet/winter21_whole
Supported extensions are: .jpg,.jpeg,.png,.ppm,.bmp,.pgm,.tif,.tiff,.webp
`

Comment: Now, the problem is so clear, `RuntimeError: Found 0 files in subfolders of: /media/data/Datasets/imagenet/winter21_whole Supported extensions are: .jpg,.jpeg,.png,.ppm,.bmp,.pgm,.tif,.tiff,.webp`. You do not have any image in winter21_whole subfolder which format is one of those formats `[.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.ppm,.bmp,.pgm,.tif,.tiff,.webp]`, you can check that out now?

Comment: Because I'm running it on a remote machine, so maybe the extension of the images is different for tars? I don't know. when i downloaded the tars and unpack them, it said .jpeg

Comment: What is the structure of the subfolders inside the main folder? You can put it in your question please/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, my first guess is to use the `root` directory, not the directory to subfolder. In your code, you can use it like:

```
trainset = ImageFolder(root = '/media/data/Datasets/imagenet/')
```

You can read [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.4.1/torchvision/datasets.html#imagefolder) more to see how to structure the folders and set the `root` when you instantiate an object from `ImageFolder`.

**The root folder should contain the folders of classes, and each class contains its own images.**